# Mailchimp and Gmail: text color issue

Tags: css, gmail, mailchimp

i've a problem with Mailchimp, but only on Gmail.
When i send test email text looks "purple" and not "white" as i wrote into code ( #FFFFFF ).

I write it into the style="..." and into "style" section `mcnTextContent { color: #FFFFFF !important; }`

Comment: I'm unfamiliar with this "!important" tag. I would expect the formatting to be strictly 'color: #<colorhash>;'

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/67136633/1554947

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned [here](https://www.campaignmonitor.com/css/), Gmail doesn't support the `<style>` tag, therefore, you would have to code your color inline like this for example...

```
<span style="color:#ffffff;">TEXT HERE</span>
```

However, as part of your email build, I'd recommend you use an [inliner](http://templates.mailchimp.com/resources/inline-css/) before you send the email out. This ensures maximum compatibility for the likes of Gmail etc.

Hope that helps!

Comment: Thank you! Solved. But how come in Gmail text is not aligned as i said in HTML?

Comment: Good stuff! If you could mark the tick, that would be great! Gmail only supports inline CSS, so anything you put in the style tags won't be supported. So aligning stuff using `align` and `float` has to be done on the HTML tags inline unfortunately!